# calculating a penalty as a percentage

Tags: percentages

I was late paying a bill and the total has gone from $124.85  to  $136.17 
I would like to know how to calculate the increase as a percentage.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{136.17-124.85}{124.85} \cdot 100\% \doteq 9\% $$

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated